# Fail to enable NFS on Yocto Linux

Tags: nfs, yocto

I'm trying to enable NFS on a Linux image built using Yocto. The image is running on a dev board - Qualcomm RB5. After booting up, mount.nfs didn't seem to work, complaining

```
mount.nfs: No such device
```

When I check using dmesg | grep nfs, I got the following info but can't figure out myself what's the reason for the failure

```
[    7.323526] systemd[597]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.326328] request_module fs-nfsd succeeded, but still no fs?
[    7.337908] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
[    7.338655] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[    7.346027] systemd[1]: nfs-mountd.service: Job nfs-mountd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[    7.346754] systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[    7.454332] systemd[649]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.459122] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
[    7.460157] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[    8.235626] systemd[726]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    8.241962] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
[    8.243164] systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I check using "`systemctl status proc-fs-nfsd.mount`", it shows the following:

```
Jan 01 06:55:40 qrb5165-rb5 mount[1377]: mount: /proc/fs/nfsd: unknown filesystem type 'nfsd'.
```

which is confusing since I thought I enabled nfs.

I made sure I enabled NFS support in local.conf. The following are the lines that I used to enable NFS:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " nfs"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "nfs-server"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "nfs-client"
```

Anything that I missed?

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of digging, I just got NFS to work on the device. The failure was caused by a newbie error that I **haven't enabled NFS filesystem support in the kernel** so there was no corresponding kernel driver being built. I guess I somehow assumed Yocto will do that for you, but actually it will not.. I added the following changes to the kernel config to enable NFS on the device:

```
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
CONFIG_NFSD=y
```